« De différents domaines » / « différents domaines ». Bonne réponse ?
Je corrige une copie d'un étudiant qui a écrit : « J'ai travaillé dans de différents domaines. »
J'ai corrigé instinctivement par « J'ai travaillé dans différents domaines. » mais je n'arrive pas à expliquer cette correction.
Il semble que « différent » est un adjectif et qu'au pluriel, « de » est obligatoire.
Pourquoi n'est-ce pas le cas ici ?

Pourquoi de serait-il obligatoire avec l'adjectif différent??

J'ai travaillé dans des domaines différents est possible, à condition que le contexte précise de quel domaine ils diffèrent. Sinon, dans des domaines variés.

@Frank Possible que l'étudiant ait confondu avec dans de nombreux domaines, qui a un sens voisin et où de est obligatoire. Que différents s'analyse comme adj. indéfini et non comme qual. épithète n'aide certes pas; pour preuve, l'OP ne peut expliquer sa correction.

@FrançoisJurain Oui, effectivement, c'est probable.

Ton instinct est bon, dans cette phrase il n' y a aucune raison de mettre de devant « différents ». Et c'est la seule phrase correcte.

J'ai travaillé dans différents domaines.

Différents (au pluriel) employé devant un nom pluriel est certes un adjectif, mais un adjectif indéfini*, pas un adjectif qualificatif, c'est à dire qu'il fonctionne comme un déterminant, ce qui le rend incompatible avec l'emploi de de, que ce de soit déterminant ou article indéfini.
Par contre on pourrait dire :

J'ai travaillé dans les différents domaines de la communication.

Dans cette dernière phrase la présence du déterminant défini « les » n'est pas lié à  l'emploi de « différents » mais entrainé par le fait que « domaines » soit défini « de la communication ».
Et dans cette autre phrase prise au hasard sur internet de, en tant que préposition, est entrainé par le verbe « venir », et n'a rien à voir avec « différents » placé juste après.

Ces mots viennent de différents domaines, dans lesquels les Arabes exerçaient un rôle majeur, notamment les sciences...

Apparemment l'erreur faite par ton élève semble fréquente, j'ai trouvé sur Linguee de très nombreuses phrases où l'emploi de « dans de différents » n'est pas justifié, et ne serait pas mis par un francophone. J'ai voulu vérifié les phrase sources, beaucoup ont disparues (erreur 404) et celles que j'ai pu vérifier proviennent de textes écrits par des non francophones.

*Il a dans ce cas un sens proche de plusieurs.

L'usage (voir ngram) montre clairement que l'on ajoute quasiment jamais "de". Idem  pour les autres  adjectifs indéfinis, i.e. aucun, autre, certain, chaque, différents, divers, l'un et l'autre, n'importe quel, maint, même, nul, pas un, plus d'un, plusieurs, quel, quelconque, quelque, tel, tout.

@Graffito Je  pense qu'il faudrait dire   « Jamais » plutôt que « quasiment jamais ». Du moins quand il est  adjectif indéfini comme je le dis dans mon explication.

Le "quasiment" vient de la statistique ngram. La différence entre "en maintes occasions" et "en de maintes occasions" est un peu moins importante, mais toujours très nette.
